# Finding frequency of CSV values in a dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe

- Dataset

  ```
   Group<-c("a1,a1,a1","a1,b1","a1","b1","c1,c1,c1","c1","d1")
   GroupElementsFrequency<-data.frame(Group)
  ```
- I am trying to find the occurence of each element and creating output like below:

GroupElementsFrequency

```
 similiar   frequency               elementsDescending
 a1,a1,a1   a1:5,c1:4,b1:2,d1:1     a1,c1,b1,d1
 a1,b1      a1:5,c1:4,b1:2,d1:1     a1,c1,b1,d1
 a1         a1:5,c1:4,b1:2,d1:1     a1,c1,b1,d1
 b1         a1:5,c1:4,b1:2,d1:1     a1,c1,b1,d1
 c1,c1,c1   a1:5,c1:4,b1:2,d1:1     a1,c1,b1,d1
 c1         a1:5,c1:4,b1:2,d1:1     a1,c1,b1,d1
 d1         a1:5,c1:4,b1:2,d1:1     a1,c1,b1,d1
```

Comment: Could you please specify your output again. Currently the first column of your output simply is your Group data and the entries of all other columns are identical in each row. Maybe you accidentally copied the wrong example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can table your strings with

```
test <- sort(table(strsplit(paste(Group, collapse = ","), ",")), decreasing = T)

> test

a1 c1 b1 d1 
 5  4  2  1
```

Then use this rather large construct to create the string for your `frequency` variable:

```
paste(unlist(lapply(Map(function(x, y) c(x, y), names(test), unname(test)), function(x) paste(x, collapse = ":"))), collapse = ",")

[1] "a1:5,c1:4,b1:2,d1:1"
```

and

```
names(test)
```

to get the sorted order:

```
> names(test)
[1] "a1" "c1" "b1" "d1"
```

Now to enhance the dataframe, use

```
GroupElementsFrequency$Frequency <- paste(unlist(lapply(Map(function(x, y) c(x, y), names(test), unname(test)), function(x) paste(x, collapse = ":"))), collapse = ",")
GroupElementsFrequency$elementsDescending <- paste(names(test), collapse = ",")
```

End result:

```
> GroupElementsFrequency
     Group           Frequency elementsDescending
1 a1,a1,a1 a1:5,c1:4,b1:2,d1:1        a1,c1,b1,d1
2    a1,b1 a1:5,c1:4,b1:2,d1:1        a1,c1,b1,d1
3       a1 a1:5,c1:4,b1:2,d1:1        a1,c1,b1,d1
4       b1 a1:5,c1:4,b1:2,d1:1        a1,c1,b1,d1
5 c1,c1,c1 a1:5,c1:4,b1:2,d1:1        a1,c1,b1,d1
6       c1 a1:5,c1:4,b1:2,d1:1        a1,c1,b1,d1
7       d1 a1:5,c1:4,b1:2,d1:1        a1,c1,b1,d1
```

---

Edit:

```
Group<-c("a1,a1,a1","a1,b1","","b1","c1,c1,c1","c1","d1")
```

To account for empty strings within `Group`, split the first step into three:

First extract the strings as a vector:

```
bugfix <- unlist(strsplit(paste(Group, collapse = ","), ","))
> bugfix
 [1] "a1" "a1" "a1" "a1" "b1" ""   "b1" "c1" "c1" "c1" "c1" "d1"
```

Then remove the empty parts with a `nchar > 0` condition:

```
bugfix <- bugfix[nchar(bugfix) > 0]
> bugfix
 [1] "a1" "a1" "a1" "a1" "b1" "b1" "c1" "c1" "c1" "c1" "d1"
```

and then continue with

```
test <- sort(table(bugfix), decreasing = T)
```

instead of the first command above, giving:

```
> test
bugfix
a1 c1 b1 d1 
 4  4  2  1
```

The `bugfix` name of the table will be ignored automatically.

---

2nd Edit:

To exclude the rows with blank values from the get go, you need to do two things.

First, use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating the dataframe:

```
Group <- c("a1,a1,a1","a1,b1","","b1","c1,c1,c1","c1","d1")
GroupElementsFrequency <- data.frame(Group, stringsAsFactors = F)

> GroupElementsFrequency
     Group
1 a1,a1,a1
2    a1,b1
3         
4       b1
5 c1,c1,c1
6       c1
7       d1
```

Then use

```
GroupElementsFrequency <- GroupElementsFrequency[nchar(GroupElementsFrequency$Group) > 0, , drop = FALSE]

> GroupElementsFrequency
     Group
1 a1,a1,a1
2    a1,b1
4       b1
5 c1,c1,c1
6       c1
7       d1
```

to drop the rows.

Comment: How can i validate that GroupElementsFrequency$Group does not have all blank values? In such case there would be no need to sort or do any operations

Comment: currently i am achieving this by doing this: `nrow(GroupElementsFrequency[GroupElementsFrequency$Group=="",])!=nrow(GroupElementsFrequency)`

Comment: Your edit is also right. I did those changes but I was trying to ask something like my above comment